# permanently redirect pages from httphandler using asp.net 4.0 routing feature

Tags: routes, webforms

my situation is that i had few important pages before in my site but those page has been rename and google cache those old pages and also those page url comes in google search and user click on those link and come to my site but see page not found error.

i want to handle this situation using asp.net 4.0 routing feature. so please advise me what would be the best approach as a result user will be redirected to new pages and old page should be permanently redirected with 301 status code  from routing code.So please give me the best advise and small sample code to handle this situation. thanks

Comment: I have some code, is the question still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add these pages to your routing page and point them where you like.

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing for a detailed overview of the MVC routing.

A better way is to set these pages to return a 301 header and redirect to the new page with the content, this will tell Google that the content has moved and top update its index without losing any of the built up external links